# Como separar vogal de consoantes em uma matriz em C

Tags: c, matriz

Olá, estou com um problema no meu código. Tenho uma matriz[6][3] que lê letras, após a leitura quero separar as vogais das consoantes. Entretanto não obtive sucesso pois todas as letras vão para a variável consoante. Alguém pode dar uma olhada no código e me dar uma luz...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(){
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
  char torto[6][3]; //TORTO[LINHA][COLUNAS]
  int c, l, vogalcont=0, consoantecont=0;
  char vogal[8], consoante[10];
  int x = 0;

  printf("\nInsira aqui as letras para a composicao da matriz do jogo([LINHA][COLUNA]).....\n");
  for (l = 0; l < 6; l++){
    for (c = 0; c < 3; ++c){
      printf("[%d][%d]: ", l,c);scanf("%s", &torto[l][c]);
    }
  }
  //VALIDAÇÃO DA MATRIZ
  for (l = 0; l < 6; l++){
    for (c = 0; c < 3; ++c){
      if((torto[l][c] == "A") || (torto[l][c] == "E") || (torto[l][c] == "I") || (torto[l][c] == "O") || (torto[l][c] == "U")){
        vogal[vogalcont] = torto[l][c];
        vogalcont++;
      }
      else{
        consoante[consoantecont] = torto[l][c];
        consoantecont++;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você declarou `torto` como

```
char torto[6][3];
```

Veja que o tipo de `torto` é `char`. Aí já começa o erro.

Para comparar strings, utilize a função `strcmp()`, da biblioteca `string.h`:

> int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
>   Compare two strings
>   Compares the C string str1 to the C string str2.
>   This function starts comparing the first character of each string. If they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs until the characters differ or until a terminating null-character is reached.
>   return value    indicates
>   < 0  the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2
>   0   the contents of both strings are equal
>   > 0  the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2

Fonte: [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comparar strings com sinal de igual é o mesmo que comparar endereços de memória. Como nenhuma string tem o mesmo endereço que outra (a não ser que sejam exatamente duas strings da mesma posição de memória), toda comparação avalia-se como `0` e o bloco `if` correspondente às comparações não é executado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* stringum = "minha terra tem palmeiras onde canta o sabia";
    char stringdois[46];
    FILE *f;
    if ((f = fopen("teste.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao criar arquivo.\n");
        return -1;
    };
    fprintf(f, "minha terra tem palmeiras onde canta o sabia");
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);

    if ((f = fopen("teste.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao criar arquivo.\n");
        return -1;
    };
    fgets(stringdois, 46, f);
    fclose(f);

    printf("stringum: %s\n", stringum);
    printf("stringdois: %s\n", stringdois);
    printf("stringum == stringdois avalia como %d\n", stringum == stringdois);
    printf("strcmp(stringum, stringdois) avalia como %d\n", strcmp(stringum, stringdois));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Qual o motivo de você definir os arrays vogal e consoante com 8 e 10 posições respectivamente? Se forem todas vogais não deveria ser vogal[18]?Idem para se não forem, aí consoante[18]?

Se quiser trabalhar caractere a caractere então utilize o formato `%c` no scanf e na comparação utilize `'` e não `"`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(){
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
  char torto[6][3]; //TORTO[LINHA][COLUNAS]
  int c, l, vogalcont=0, consoantecont=0;
  char vogal[8], consoante[10];
  int x = 0;

  printf("\nInsira aqui as letras para a composicao da matriz do jogo([LINHA][COLUNA]).....\n");
  for (l = 0; l < 6; l++){
    for (c = 0; c < 3; ++c){
      printf("[%d][%d]: ", l,c);scanf("%c", &torto[l][c]);
    }
  }
  //VALIDAÇÃO DA MATRIZ
  for (l = 0; l < 6; l++){
    for (c = 0; c < 3; ++c){
      if((torto[l][c] == 'A') || (torto[l][c] == 'E') || (torto[l][c] == 'I') || (torto[l][c] == 'O') || (torto[l][c] == 'U')){
        vogal[vogalcont] = torto[l][c];
        vogalcont++;
      }
      else{
        consoante[consoantecont] = torto[l][c];
        consoantecont++;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Registre-se que este é um programa do tipo "lê e esquece". Você nem imprime as quantidades de tipos de letras encontradas.